# Exception when using filter to retrieve a django model

Tags: python, django

To retrieve a django object, I am using the filter function as follows:

```
product = Product.objects.filter(code=request.POST['code'])
```

Then, when I try to access the retrieved object as:

```
product[0].description
```

I get an exception "list index out of range". Although, the filter is indeed returning an object because the len(product) call is showing "1".

However, if I hardcode the code value (retreived from the post above), I get no exception. 
All I want to do is get access to the product object based on the code.

Using Product.objects.get does not work either...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably validate that `request.POST['code']` is valid before you try to use it in anything:

```
# code will be None if it isn't found in request.POST
code = request.POST.get('code')
if code:
    products = Product.objects.filter(code=code)
    for product in products:
        print product.description
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer but in this type of case, where the results make no sense, it's normally time to get the debugger out (either pdb or preferably ipdb).

```
import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
```

Then look at product. What actually is it? Look at request.POST['code'] and see what is different from just passing a literal. Also would be interested to know what the attempt to use 'get' actually does. You say it doesn't work but what does it actually do?